# magento Notice: Array to string conversion lib\Varien\Data\Form\Element\Image.php on line 57

Tags: magento-1.7, magento

I am using magento 1.7 here is some problem i can't understand this i have create extension and using image type field in form when i select a image then save this goes successfully but when i edit and without make change click on save then i got this following error do you have any solution for this

```
Notice: Array to string conversion  in D:\wamp\www\easyshop\lib\Varien\Data\Form\Element\Image.php on line 57

#0 D:\wamp\www\easyshop\lib\Varien\Data\Form\Element\Image.php(57): mageCoreErrorHandler(8, 'Array to string...', 'D:\wamp\www\eas...', 57, Array)
#1 D:\wamp\www\easyshop\app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\widget\form\renderer\fieldset\element.phtml(40): Varien_Data_Form_Element_Image->getElementHtml()
#2 D:\wamp\www\easyshop\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(241): include('D:\wamp\www\eas...')
#3 D:\wamp\www\easyshop\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml\defau...')
#4 D:\wamp\www\easyshop\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#5 D:\wamp\www\easyshop\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#6 D:\wamp\www\easyshop\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(863): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#7 D:\wamp\www\easyshop\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Widget\Form\Renderer\Fieldset\Element.php(52): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#8 D:\wamp\www\easyshop\lib\Varien\Data\Form\Element\Abstract.php(223): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Renderer_Fieldset_Element->render(Object(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Image))
#9 D:\wamp\www\easyshop\lib\Varien\Data\Form\Element\Abstract.php(233): Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract->getHtml()
#10 D:\wamp\www\easyshop\lib\Varien\Data\Form\Element\Fieldset.php(90): Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract->toHtml()
#11 D:\wamp\www\easyshop\app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\widget\form\renderer\fieldset.phtml(49): Varien_Data_Form_Element_Fieldset->getChildrenHtml()
#12 D:\wamp\www\easyshop\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(241): include('D:\wamp\www\eas...')
#13 D:\wamp\www\easyshop\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml\defau...')
#14 D:\wamp\www\easyshop\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#15 D:\wamp\www\easyshop\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#16 D:\wamp\www\easyshop\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(863): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#17 D:\wamp\www\easyshop\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Widget\Form\Renderer\Fieldset.php(51): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#18 D:\wamp\www\easyshop\lib\Varien\Data\Form\Element\Abstract.php(223): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Renderer_Fieldset->render(Object(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Fieldset))
#19 D:\wamp\www\easyshop\lib\Varien\Data\Form\Element\Abstract.php(233): Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract->getHtml()
#20 D:\wamp\www\easyshop\lib\Varien\Data\Form.php(244): Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract->toHtml()
#21 D:\wamp\www\easyshop\lib\Varien\Data\Form.php(256): Varien_Data_Form->toHtml()
#22 D:\wamp\www\easyshop\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Widget\Form.php(108): Varien_Data_Form->getHtml()
#23 D:\wamp\www\easyshop\app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\widget\form.phtml(28): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form->getFormHtml()
#24 D:\wamp\www\easyshop\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(241): include('D:\wamp\www\eas...')
#25 D:\wamp\www\easyshop\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml\defau...')
#26 D:\wamp\www\easyshop\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#27 D:\wamp\www\easyshop\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#28 D:\wamp\www\easyshop\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(863): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#29 D:\wamp\www\easyshop\app\code\local\Easyshop\Slider\Block\Adminhtml\Slider\Edit\Tabs.php(19): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#30 D:\wamp\www\easyshop\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(862): Easyshop_Slider_Block_Adminhtml_Slider_Edit_Tabs->_beforeToHtml()
#31 D:\wamp\www\easyshop\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Text\List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#32 D:\wamp\www\easyshop\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#33 D:\wamp\www\easyshop\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(582): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#34 D:\wamp\www\easyshop\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(526): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('left', true)
#35 D:\wamp\www\easyshop\app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\page.phtml(58): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('left')
#36 D:\wamp\www\easyshop\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(241): include('D:\wamp\www\eas...')
#37 D:\wamp\www\easyshop\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml\defau...')
#38 D:\wamp\www\easyshop\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#39 D:\wamp\www\easyshop\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#40 D:\wamp\www\easyshop\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(863): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#41 D:\wamp\www\easyshop\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#42 D:\wamp\www\easyshop\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#43 D:\wamp\www\easyshop\app\code\local\Easyshop\Slider\controllers\Adminhtml\SliderController.php(44): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#44 D:\wamp\www\easyshop\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(419): Easyshop_Slider_Adminhtml_SliderController->editAction()
#45 D:\wamp\www\easyshop\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Router\Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('edit')
#46 D:\wamp\www\easyshop\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#47 D:\wamp\www\easyshop\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#48 D:\wamp\www\easyshop\app\Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#49 D:\wamp\www\easyshop\index.php(88): Mage::run('', 'store')
#50 {main}
```

and i use following code to add image type field

```
  $fieldset->addField('filename', 'image', array(
      'label'     => Mage::helper('slider')->__('File'),
      'required'  => false,
      'name'      => 'filename',
  ));
```

Please help me to solve this issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just try code like following. because in edit mode when user nothing did with image not select for deletion nor selected new image then you must be remove element from data so magento will ignore image field and this issue will be resolved. i have same problem so that i know solutions after tried several r&d

```
if (isset($_FILES['filename']['name']) && $_FILES['filename']['name'] != '') {
    /* 
        Move uploaded file logic when user select a image
    */
} else {

    if(isset($data['filename']['delete']) && $data['filename']['delete'] == 1) {
        /*
            When user click on checkbox for deletion
        */
        $data['filename'] = '';
    } else {
        /* 
            in edit mode when user nothing did with image not 
            select for deletion nor selected new image then you must 
            be remove element from data so magento will ignore image 
            field and this issue will be resolved
        */
        unset($data['filename']);
    }
}
```

Comment: X-Ref as the answer on it's own leaves open ends here and there: [Magento Admin Custom Module Common Problems](https://indiestechtips.wordpress.com/2012/12/22/magento-admin-custom-module-common-problems/) (Dec 2012)